# Regex Operation to find string inside a custom tag from string

Tags: c#, regex

Hi I have a string like this

```
    "[fconsender]Username (11:00 AM):[/fconsender] Hi Good Afternoon!"
```

or

```
    "[fconreceiver]AnotherUser (11:02 AM):[/fconreceiver] Yea! How are you ?"
```

I want to extract the string inside [fconsender] and [/fconsender] or
[fconreceiver] and [/fconreceiver]...
How can I simply achieve it using Regex.... 
Its just to seperate the user and chat string...

Comment: No.. I dont know anything about Regex...

Comment: Then learn about it! Here is the manual with simple examples. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @LumpN I find this one better: [www.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this pattern:

**PATTERN**

```
(?<=\[fconsender\])(.+?)(?=\[\/fconsender\])|(?<=\[fconreceiver\])(.+?)(?=\[\/fconreceiver\])
```

**C# code**

```
string regex = @"(?<=\[fconsender\])(.+?)(?=\[\/fconsender\])|(?<=\[fconreceiver\])(.+?)(?=\[\/fconreceiver\])";

string myString = "[fconreceiver]AnotherUser (11:02 AM):[/fconreceiver] Yea! How are you ?" +
                  "[fconsender]Username (11:00 AM):[/fconsender] Hi Good Afternoon!";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(myString, regex);

foreach(Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**INPUT**

> [fconsender]Username (11:00 AM):[/fconsender] Hi Good Afternoon!
>
> [fconreceiver]AnotherUser (11:02 AM):[/fconreceiver] Yea! How are you ?

**OUTPUT**

```
Username (11:00 AM):
AnotherUser (11:02 AM):
```

**EDIT**

Pattern for the chatstring as OP requested:

**PATTERN**

```
(?<=\[\/fconsender\] )(.+?)(?=\n|$|\[)|(?<=\[\/fconreceiver\] )(.+?)(?=\n|$|\[)
```

**INPUT**

> [fconsender]Username (11:00 AM):[/fconsender] Hi Good Afternoon!
>
> [fconreceiver]AnotherUser (11:02 AM):[/fconreceiver] Yea! How are you ?

**OUTPUT**

```
Hi Good Afternoon!
Yea! How are you ?
```

Comment: Hi, I used this 
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?<=\[fcsender\])(.+?)(?=\[\/fcsender\])|(?<=\[fcreceiver\])(.+?)(?=\[\/fcreceiver\])");
            string[] splitstr = rg.Split(text);

It returns  This Output
   [0]: "[fcsender]"
   [1]: "Me [12:56]"
   [2]: "[/fcsender]: Hai"

How can I remove those tags & return only Username and Chatstring only as two strings ?

Comment: @YesudassMoses Bro this formatting sucks, can't read it :/ Use the C# code I gave u.

Comment: Yea It works well,,,
But I want to split strings... 
As Username, and the chat strings.... :(

Comment: @YesudassMoses great : )

Comment: I didnt write it in question... my mistake :(

Comment: @YesudassMoses Well, if you want to get the chatstring it's easy, you just have to modify a bit the regex I gave you, and you will get another pattern for the chatstrings only.

Comment: Yea,,, which pattern I can use for chat strings only ?

Comment: Can I use double quotes to escape the quotes inside the pattern ?

Comment: @YesudassMoses yeah I've just realized it will not work in C#, Do you use the regex on each line separately or on all lines together? Answer this and I will modify the pattern so it will work : )

Comment: If a chat is coming, or sending It will be just one line,,, 
But if I load the saved chat from a file,, It will be a group of lines 
having these tags in each line....

Comment: @YesudassMoses Hmm gimme a sec ill try to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and helping mentality bro :)

Comment: @YesudassMoses No problem ; ) Well edited it once again so it will use regardless you use to separate the lines.

Comment: Both Patterns returns No matches.... I used this Text

[fconsender]Me [13:27][/fconsender]: hi

Comment: @YesudassMoses so it works properly, you have to be consistant in the text formatting once u use **space** after `[/fconsender]` once **:**. What do you want to use? Both? Because one time u use **:** before closing tag and one time after it.

Comment: "[fconsender]Me [13:37]: [/fconsender]Hai"
It was a mistake... I changed string like this,,, and first one works But not getting the chat string

Comment: @YesudassMoses Because there is no space after the closing tag now. You want it there or not? First in both examples you have used a space there.

Comment: Aiwa... ! Its working now,,, 
So I should follow this type of formating for all my strings passed to the regex right :)

Comment: @YesudassMoses yeah as regex always base on a **CERTAIN** pattern, that's why it's called **regular** expression ; ). No problemo ; )

Comment: :-) :-) :-) :-) :-) :-)

Comment: @YesudassMoses salary is too low hahahah, I'm programmer and want it to stay that way :D Anyway thanks for the compliment : )

Answer (score 0):

Just use [[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+](?.*)[/[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+] and extract the content group match to retrieve the match

Comment: It shows errror
parsing "[[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+](?.*)[/[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+]" - Unrecognized grouping construct.

Comment: For C# you should use @"\[[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\](?<test>.*)\[/[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\]"

Comment: Use http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx for testing the expression